# Sqlite3 – How can I get the timestamp from the result of SELECT max

Tags: python, sqlite

My table is set up with columns for ID, Time, AAC, AAD, etc. The Time is the timestamp when the data was entered.

How am I able to get the value of the timestamp at the max value for each column?

```
import sqlite3

sqlite_file = 'foo.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()
column = ['AAC', 'AAD', 'ABC', 'ABP', 
          'AGL', 'AHG', 'AHY', 'AIO']
for i in range(len(column)):
    c.execute("SELECT max("'"%s"'") FROM prices" % (column[i]))
    print (column[i], c.fetchone())
conn.close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SQLite 3.7.11 or later (check `sqlite3.sqlite_version`), other column values are guaranteed to come from the row that matches the MAX() or MIN():

```sql
SELECT max(AAC), Time FROM prices;
```

Comment: Hmm both answers are correct thank you. But for simplicity, I've just upgraded my sqlite3 version and am using this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to select desired column along with timestamp and by arranging the desired column by descending order. And lastly selecting only 1 row will do the job.

```sql
SELECT column_name,Time FROM prices order by column_name desc limit 1
```

where `column_name` is AAC, AAD etc. Limit 1 will return only the row with max value for the desired column.